# Content esclusion on some page

Tags: php, laravel

Hi all i will be needing an assistance. I have a navbar that all link on my app use but i will like to seclude a search form from some of the link in the app but am having difficulty doing that. This what i have tried on my nabvar so far example

Tried using route but no success

```
@if( (route('portfolio') &&(route('portfolio.details) 
      content here
@else 
      content 
@endif
```

then i tried targeting the URI

```
@if( Request::is('/portfolio') &&(route('portfolio/details) 
     content here
@else 
     content 
@endif
```

None seems to working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be using the route helper method in your if statement.  I think if you just do something like this, it should work.

```
@if (request()->is('portfolio'))
  content
@else
  content
@endif
```

Comment: My method was working as well i wasn't just confident. Thanks man.